# Calling scriptDb.saveBatch with ~7600 items results in a rateMax error

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on an apps script to periodically check for modified items on a web service. Because API calls were taking too long, I've been trying to cache some of the data periodically in ScriptDb. However, trying to update data using `scriptDb.saveBatch` always results in the following error:

```
Service invoked too many times in a short time: scriptdb rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.
```

My script is querying ScriptDb and returning a result set of ~7600 records, modifying those records, and then saving everything back in a batch. I can't think of any way, given the tools Google makes available, to reduce the number of database calls I make. Is this really too much for ScriptDb to handle, or is there some way to improve on my code?

```
function getRootFolders() {
  var updateTimestamp = new Date().valueOf();

  var results = GetModifiedFolders(ROOT_FOLDER); //Returns results from an API call
  var data = results.data; //The actual data from the API, as an array
  var len = data.length;

  if (len > 0) {    
    //Get a collection of dbMaps from ScriptDb
    var maps = {}; //Store as an object for easy updating
    var getMaps = db.query({'type': 'baseFolder'}).limit(50000); //Returns 7621 items

    while (getMaps.hasNext()) {
      var map = getMaps.next();
      maps[map.boxId] = map;
    }

    //Iterate through the results
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      var item = data[i];  
      var map = maps[item.boxId]; //Try to retrive an existing dbMap
      if (map) { //If it exists, update the existing dbMap
        map.modified = item.modified;
        map.updateTimestamp = updateTimestamp;
      }
      else { //Otherwise, insert the result into the collection of dbMaps   
        item.type = 'baseFolder';
        item.updateTimestamp = updateTimestamp;   
        maps[item.boxId] = item;
      }
    }

    //Convert the object back to an array, and use that to save to ScriptDb
    var toSave = [];
    for (var prop in dbMaps) {
      toSave.push(dbMaps[prop]);
    }

    var mutations = db.saveBatch(toSave, false); //FAIL with scriptdb rateMax
    if (db.allOk(mutations)) {
      ( . . . )
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've made a few changes in an effort to stop this from happening, but to no avail. I'm sleeping for several minutes before calling `saveBatch`, **and** then I'm saving in multiple, smaller batches, sleeping in between each one.

At this point, I can't imagine why I'm still getting this rateMax error. Is there something wrong with my code that I'm missing, or is this a bug in apps script? I assume it's my fault, but I can't see it.

Here's what I've added:

```
//Retrieving data from the API takes ~1 minute

//Sleep for a while to avoid rateMax error
var waitUntil = updateTimestamp + 240000; //Wait until there's only 1 minute left in the 5 minute quota
var msToWait = waitUntil - (now.valueOf());
Utilities.sleep(msToWait); //Sleep for ~3 minutes

//Save in batches
var batchSize = 250;
var batch = [];
var i = 0;
for (var prop in maps) {
  batch.push(maps[prop]);
  i++;

  //When the batch reaches full size, save it
  if (i % batchSize == 0 || i == len) {
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    var mutations = db.saveBatch(batch, false);
    if (!db.allOk(mutations)) {
      return false;
    }
    batch = [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the batch in smaller parts.
Wont affect the code because batch is not atomic anyways.

Comment: Wouldn't that just make more scriptdb calls?

Comment: Oh, I think I may see what you mean. I can break the batch into parts, and then call `Utilities.sleep` in between saving each batch. Giving it a try now.

Comment: not clear why u need to do the first sleep (3 minutes). Also put more info about what doesnt work.

Comment: aha I see, you put it there to attempt avoiding a rate_max but that wont help since you are sleeping before and not in between operations thus its a no-op. Sleep in between batches, and for longer, possibly proportional to the number of elements in the array being commited.

Comment: I'm sleeping in between batches, too. I've tried to sleep anywhere I can, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: see the part in my comment about sleeping proportional to batch size. for example as an experiment, change your sleep(1000) inside the loop to be sleep(20000). you need to calibrate it

Comment: Yeesh, I'll give it a try, but I hope that's not the answer. Wouldn't that make the existence of `saveBatch` pointless? There would be no advantage over just saving an item at a time. And if I have to sleep one second per record, that would mean I can never save more than 3,000 records in a single execution.

Comment: Sorry to tell you but Im sure thats the answer. saveBatch in fact doesnt have an advantage other than maybe a slight speed advantage. if it ever implements the "atomic" flag if would be an advantage but it hasnt. as with anything in apps script, its limited how much data you can process in a given timeframe.

Comment: As much as I hate to admit it, it does appear you're right. I really do need to wait a second for every single record being saved. Because of that, I've just scrapped calls to `saveBatch` and I'm saving records one at a time until I'm out of time. Thank you so much for sticking with me and talking me through this!

Comment: Youre welcome. Also remember not to rely on experimental apis like scriptDb for any critical/customer code.